# No actualiza fichero javascript

Tags: javascript, dns

Tengo un VPS y una aplicación web y se me dan estos 2 casos:

1º Entrando por ip      => xx.xx.xx.xx/myapp   => veo el fichero actualizado js actualizado

2º Entrando por dominio => www.midominio/myapp => no veo el fichero actualizado js actualizado

Tengo configurado los dns en Cloudflare de forma gratuita y no se si esto afecta en algo.

PD: he borrado cache, temporales del tomcat,..

Mi app esta desplegado en un tomcat y la redirección la hago mediando un apache

Comment: ¿Lo sirves directamente desde tomcat o tienes algo delante (un Apache/Nginx) como proxy inverso?

Comment: actualiado mi post con tu pregunta

Comment: Puede ser que Apache lo haya cacheado para no "molestar" a Tomcat con peticiones de *assets* (contenido estático)

Comment: Efectivamente, estaba mirando la configuracion del cloudfare y era eso, el cache, lo he limpiado y ya esta